# Linear Regression for Stock Prediction in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, linear-regression

I am on the final part of my data analysis project. My professor recommended that I use Linear Regression to estimate the stock price for Turkish Airlines at the end of the year. I'll be entirely honest, I don't think I quite understand how to get what he's looking for. This is the code I have so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

Stock_predict_2020 %>% ggplot(aes(Date, Close)) + 
  geom_line(color = "blue") + 
  labs(title = "Turkish Airlines' Daily Stock Price for Nov.-Dec. 2020", 
       subtitle = "Source: Yahoo Finance",
       y = "Final Stock Price (in Dollars)")

        
linearmodel = lm(Date~Close, data = Stock_predict_2020)       


linearmodel
```

The Stock_predict_2020 object is just the spreadsheet of stock prices between November and December of 2020 that I got off of Yahoo Finance. I used the base `lm` function but I don't think I did it correctly. I would like to predict the stock price at a specific date nearing the end of the year using data from the past 12 months.

This is the output I managed to get:
[image: nonsensical output]

I woud like to use the `geom_abline()` function to plot the line through the financial data throughout the year. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You now predict date as a function of close (should be reversed).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Thanks again for all the help! I used the slope and intercept from the output to calculate the potential stock price on the last day of the year!

```
linearmodel = lm(Close~Date, data = Stock_predict_2020)

linearmodel #generated output with slope and intercept.
```